# Which's the best performance between multiFaceDetection VS Face tracking (in multi faces)

Tags: opencv, emgucv

I was tried to detect all faces in live picture (from camera) this detection refreshed every 3 seconds and draw a rectangle around the face
but the disadvantage of this way that if the face have been moved the rectangle remains in it's place

I followed other way (tracking) to track the face during the move
My question : when tracking more than one face is performance will be satisfactory

Comment: Why would not detect faces in every frame?

Comment: because it's very heavy operation but the tracking in lighter

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of possible answers to this (based on resolution, color depth, etc.).

But here's what I'd do:
At first, scan the whole image for faces. Once you've found one, try to find it only in the vicinity in the following frames (define an area around with an appropriate border where it could have moved to). Also use a filter (e.g. alpha/beta filter) to try to predict the face's position/movement). If a face is lost for more than x frames (or in general, every y frames) do a new complete scan to catch new and lost faces. In general I wouldn't advice on scanning the whole frame every time. The more pixels you're able to skip ("it can't be there anyway") - even if it' just the top or border space where you've never seen a face yet - will net you some performance gain.

Comment: but can i track multi face in the same frame

Comment: Really depends on the performance of your platform. The faster it is, the more you can expect. Don't see any general restriction keeping you from doing it.

Comment: Yes you can track as many faces as the process can locate, your best bet is a haar classifier which EMGU has plenty off. If you look at the examples you will see a foreach loop that draws a rectangle round each face found to speed up the process work only with greyscale images and reduce there resolution 320x240 should provide enough detail for a good frame rate. Remember while you detect on a smaller image you can upscale the results and draw the results on the original sized image. If you need examples let me know, Cheers